# NuxtJS Content bug @nuxtjs/content

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

when i add @nuxtjs/content to my project i get this error :

(node:17080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at WebSocket.setSocket (C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop\Main\Job Trainer\nuxtContent\contentNuxt\node_modules@nuxt\content\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:165:14)
    at WebSocketServer.completeUpgrade (C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop\Main\Job Trainer\nuxtContent\contentNuxt\node_modules@nuxt\content\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket-server.js:322:8)
    at WebSocketServer.handleUpgrade (C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop\Main\Job Trainer\nuxtContent\contentNuxt\node_modules@nuxt\content\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket-server.js:245:10)
    at WS.handleUpgrade (C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop\Main\Job Trainer\nuxtContent\contentNuxt\node_modules@nuxt\content\lib\ws.js:21:21)
    at WS.serve (C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop\Main\Job Trainer\nuxtContent\contentNuxt\node_modules@nuxt\content\lib\ws.js:17:10)
    at C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop\Main\Job Trainer\nuxtContent\contentNuxt\node_modules@nuxt\content\lib\middleware.js:11:15
    at call (C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop\Main\Job Trainer\nuxtContent\contentNuxt\node_modules\connect\index.js:239:7)
    at next (C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop\Main\Job Trainer\nuxtContent\contentNuxt\node_modules\connect\index.js:183:5)
    at next (C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop\Main\Job Trainer\nuxtContent\contentNuxt\node_modules\connect\index.js:161:14)
    at WebpackBundler.middleware (C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop\Main\Job Trainer\nuxtContent\contentNuxt\node_modules@nuxt\webpack\dist\webpack.js:5410:5)
(node:17080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise 
which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)

Node Version : v12.18.0
NuxtJS Version : 2.0.0